# Clearing input field on firebase function after angular submit

Tags: angularjs, input, firebase

The function works and submits the user input to my firebase "back-end" but I cannot figure out a clear function to empty out the input field after using ng-submit.  The input is tied to the var "emailInput" with ng-model.  Thanks for any suggestions!

```
var newEmailref = new Firebase("https://nevermind.com");
$scope.email = $firebaseArray(newEmailref);
$scope.addEmail = function(email) {
    $scope.email.$add(email);
    $scope.emailInput = '';
};
```

Comment: Show your **html** code.

Comment: <form id="subscribe" ng-submit="addEmail(emailInput)"><input type="email" placeholder="Email Subscribe" ng-model="emailInput"></input></form>

Answer (score 0):

I needed to assign a key to the email input and also an empty object.

```
$scope.emailInput = {};
var newEmailref = new Firebase("https://archerthedog.firebaseio.com/email");
    $scope.email = $firebaseArray(newEmailref);
    $scope.addEmail = function(email) {
        $scope.email.$add(email);
        $scope.emailInput = {};
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just needs a small modification to use `$scope.email = "";` instead of `$scope.emailInput = '';`:

```
var newEmailref = new Firebase("https://nevermind.com");
$scope.email = $firebaseArray(newEmailref);
$scope.addEmail = function(email) {
  $scope.email.$add(email);
  $scope.email = '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get you.... If add a item in firebase database the database will create key value,
      if you doing like this

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('players/');

      ref.orderByValue().on("value", function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(takenData) {
             console.log("The " + takenData.key + " rating is " + 
      takenData.val().email);
       });
     });
```

The console.log answer will be for takenData.key is some id value like 
     (-Ko7cGuymlshrS2JQEEC)
     Then takenData.val().email) is an email address...

Answer (score 0):

```
       See the Full code of mine it's working for me

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var firebasedata = $firebaseObject(ref);



  var messagesRef = ref.child("storeUserData");
  var data = $firebaseArray(messagesRef)

  $scope.createItem= function(user) {
        data.$add(user).then(function(data) {
           $scope.user = "";
              var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
           title: 'Dear User, Your Account has created Successfully',
         });
      $timeout(function() {
          myPopup.close(); //close the popup after 6 seconds for some reason
       }, 6000);
         });
      }
      ref.orderByValue().on("value", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(takenData) {
         console.log("The " + takenData.key + " rating is " + 
       takenData.val().email);
        });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to enable the help-guide when writing your answer. Your formatting needs some improvements to understand your code better. You can edit an answer of your own if it's not right yet instead of writing a new answer every time ;).

Comment: So edit one of your answers here until it looks okay and then delete the other one so you only have one answer here